# how to add extra more than one extras in share intent?

Tags: android

I am jus doing a simple game app "flames" I need the result and name of the two persons to be shared .The sharing works properly!but iam able to share only the final ans 
          "marriage" or "friends" etc bt i need the boy name and girl name and the result should be shared simultaneouly like "anu" and" hari" will be "friends"..!! how can i add extra two intent for name1 and name2 in this for sharing them?iam a beginneer plz help!!

```
    String text = "http://www.twistedequations.com";
    ans = (String) output.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ans);

    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you can append your answer in one string and pass share that string.

Comment: how to append the string..?its beter if i know som example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your answer is "friends" then you need like this

```
 ans = (String) output.getText();

 String name1 = edt1.getText().toString();
 String name2 = edt2.getText().toString();

 String myvalue = name1+" "+ name2 +" "+"will be"+ ans;
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myvalue);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Share using"));
```

Where ans string stands for friends or marriage result as per your question.

You can also use concat() function for String.

Comment: so I am supposed to add

Comment: String myvalue=name1+name2+ans. Is it correct cz even we dont know name1 and name2.so should v append lik ts?

Comment: so how can you get name1 and name2? means from edittext or TextView?

Comment: iam getting error in intent if i use as per ur code?can i use ACTION_SEND MULTIPLE to send multiple datas?

Comment: @anusha you can send using single because in that only your one string will be shared.

Comment: @anusha have you checked?

Comment: i getting error in string..!! the method is undefined for type string!!

Comment: In this line ans = (String) output.getText();?

Comment: i resolved the error in string and now iam getting same error in intent..Intent cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Comment: You have to import that Intent.Put cursor on it and fix the problem import it.

Comment: have already imported!!only after changing the code iam getting ts error

Comment: problem is in the string!! when i remove the string intent error goes off!!

Comment: you have placed at wrong place that's why problem. Show me your updated code after you have changed.

Comment: @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
         String text = "http://www.twistedequations.com";
  
 String names = name.getText().toString();
 String nameshare = name1.getText().toString();

            String myvalue = name+" "+ name1 +" "+"will be"+                 ans.
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, myvalue);
   intent.setType("text/plain");
   startActivity(intent);}
        }

Comment: @anusha this is because there is syntax error..thats why. you have placed ur code at wrong place...your brackets are not properly closed.

Comment: Other is not problem. Now your code is perfect. You need to paste it right place.

Comment: I checked it!!i have closed it properly mr.piyush. but problem is stil in the intent

Comment: Change here from String myvalue = name1+" "+ name2 +" "+"will be"+ ans. to String myvalue = name1+" "+ name2 +" "+"will be"+ ans;

Comment: Its working bt instead getting name of two person and output iam getting"android.widget.TextVew@4185daf0 android.widget.TextView@4185e848

Comment: Have you set Text for all that? Or dynamically it will set to TextView?

Comment: Aur tum EditText se data fetch karva rahi ho ya fir TextView me se??

Comment: @anusha You'r wel come. Glad to help you!!Accept this as a answer so for other same like you is good solution to them.

Comment: Sure mr.Piyush!!help me for other pblmz if it arises!! wil be pleasd!!